# Print a DWORD's value as an ASCII character

Tags: assembly, ascii, masm, masm32

I have a very simple program where I've stored a number in a `dw` variable called `asciiCode`. I want to then use the `print` macro declared in `masm32rt.inc` to print the ASCII character represented by this value, `A`, but attempting to do this crashes the program:

```
.386
option casemap:none

include \masm32\include\masm32rt.inc

.data
    asciiCode dw 65

.code 
start:
    print asciiCode
    exit
end start
```

The program still crashes when `asciiCode` is declared as a  `db` or `dd`.

Is there another function that I must use first to convert this `dw` into a printable ASCII character?

Comment: You could just look at what that macro actually assembles to, with a disassembler or better by single-stepping in a debugger.  Most mistakes in asm programs make them crash, that's why you need a debugger.

Comment: @PeterCordes What beginner-friendly debugger would you recommend for Windows?

Comment: IDK, I use gdb on Linux.  IIRC from the one time I did Windows development, visual studio can debug asm, so that's an option if you're using it already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way might be to use the `printf` macro:

```
; prints 65. If you want the character A instead, use the format specifier %c
printf("%d", asciiCode)
```

You should probably declare `asciiCode` using `dd` in this case - `dw` gives you a *word*, not a *dword*.

Comment: Ah-ha! Thanks for pointing me to `printf`, using `"%c"` as the format string does print `A`.